# Tensorflow Keras Dataset Load Huge Multiple Numpy Files

Tags: python, tensorflow

How to load multiple numpy files into dataset?

```py
    def train(self):
        dataset = self.read_dataset(
            'DATASET/*.npz', tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN)
        batch_size = 128
        nb_epochs = 1500
        self.model.fit(
            dataset,
            batch_size=batch_size,
            epochs=nb_epochs,
            verbose=self.verbose,
            validation_split=0.1,
            callbacks=self.callbacks,
        )

    def read_dataset(self, filename, mode, batch_size=512):
        def _input_fn():
            def load_numpy(npzfile):
                print(f'Reading {npzfile}')
                npz = np.load(npzfile)
                features = npz['x']
                labels = npz['y']
                return features, labels

            # Create list of files that match pattern
            file_list = tf.gfile.Glob(filename)

            # Create dataset from file list
            dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(
                file_list).flat_map(load_numpy)
            if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN:
                num_epochs = None
                dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=10 * batch_size)
            else:
                num_epochs = 1

            dataset = dataset.repeat(num_epochs).batch(batch_size)
            return dataset.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()
        return _input_fn
```

I'm following [this article](https://towardsdatascience.com/getting-data-into-tensorflow-estimator-models-3432f404a8da) but got this error 
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'ndim'
  File "train.py", line 27, in 
    model.train()

Comment: Hi @Putra Ardiansyah, Can you provide a minimum reproducible code or at least a runnable code in google colab that replicates the error?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to recreate your error and it occurs when we feed a list of strings to a model which is something it does not expect. It has to be converted to an integer sequence before feeding to the model. Also better to pass `as.array(input)` to `model.fit()` if your `input` is a list, because sometimes when you pass a list to `model.fit()`, it tries to get shape of input by reading `ndim` attribute of numpy array and fails.

Example:

```
%tensorflow_version 1.x
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)
import numpy as np
from numpy import loadtxt
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense

x = ['x','x','x','x','x','x','x','x','x','y','y']
y = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0]

# define model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(12, input_dim=1, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(8, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

# compile model
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

# Model Summary
model.summary()

# Fit the model
model.fit(x, y, epochs=150, batch_size=10, verbose=0)
```

Output -

```
1.9.0
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 12)                24        
_________________________________________________________________
dense_4 (Dense)              (None, 8)                 104       
_________________________________________________________________
dense_5 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 9         
=================================================================
Total params: 137
Trainable params: 137
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-4867cb6c9deb> in <module>()
     24 
     25 # Fit the model
---> 26 model.fit(x, y, epochs=150, batch_size=10, verbose=0)

4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training_utils.py in standardize_single_array(x)
     79   elif tensor_util.is_tensor(x):
     80     return x
---> 81   elif x.ndim == 1:
     82     x = np.expand_dims(x, 1)
     83   return x

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'ndim'
```